# Check if String contains any letters from array - JAVA

Tags: java

```
    String [] V = {"a","e","i","o","u"};

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String A;
    System.out.println("Enter any letters");
    A=input.next();

    if(A.contains(V)) {
        System.out.println("success");
    }
```

bottom line. if any of the letters in "V" string are in "A" i want it to continue to "success"

Comment: i think you need to check for each element individually using loop.

Comment: If you can use third party dependency, there is the [containsAny](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsAny%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20char...%29) method in `StringUtils` class from Apache commons-lang. But if you can't, simply check each element as YoungHobbit said.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `foreach` loop like this:

```
        for (String string : V) {

            if(A.contains(string)) {
                System.out.println("success");
            }
        }
```

Because the method `contains(CharSequence)` in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String[]).

Answer (score 0):

**It Works Making some changes to your code**

```
String [] V = {"a","e","i","o","u"};
    boolean flag = false;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String A;
    System.out.println("Enter any letters");
    A=input.next();

    for(String temp:V)
    {
        if (A.contains(temp)) {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(flag)
        System.out.println("Success");
    else
        System.out.println("Not Success");
```

Comment: you can `break` out of the `for` loop when the flag gets set to true - no need to keep checking when that happens